# How to properly store multiple res.androidlib when importing plugins which have their own res?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

In my project i have Google Play Games plugin which has ExternalDependencyManager, i want to import AppsFlyer witch also needs to import ExternalDependencyManager, to import AppsFlyer without ExternalDependencyManager following guide on github i should manually download files which have folder res which can't be stored in unity anymore - https://forum.unity.com/threads/exc...s-plugins-android-assets-was-removed.1171829/.

I should use res.androidlib instead, but i already have res.androidlib for FileProvider.
How to store 3 res folders from files for AppsFlyer and with my res.androidlib for FileProvider?

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from unity forum:

It has to be .androidlib folder with res or assets or similar inside of it. It does not have to be literally named res.androidlib.
That is, come up with unique names for your libraries.